# How to Aggregate records in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a following csv file (each line is dynamic number of characters but the columns are fixed... hope i am making sense)

```
   **001**     Math        **02/20/2013**  A

   **001**     Literature  **03/02/2013**  B

   **002**     Biology     **01/01/2013**  A

   **003**     Biology     **04/08/2013**  A

   **001**     Biology     **05/01/2013**  B

   **002**     Math        **03/10/2013**  C
```

I am trying to get results into another csv file in the following format where it is grouped by student id and order by date ascending order.

```
   001,#Math;A;02/20/2013#Biology;B;05/01/2013#Literature;B;03/02/2013

   002,#Biology;A;01/01/2013#Math;C;03/10/2013

   003,#Biology;A;04/08/2013
```

There is one constraint though. **The input file is huge around 200 millions rows.** I tried using c# and storing it DB and write sql query. Its very slow and not accepted. After googling i hear python is very powerful for these operations. I am new to Python started playing with the code. I really appreciate the PYTHON gurus to help me to get the results as I mentioned above.

Comment: Does every line in the file use a fixed number of characters? Because it may help to provide a faster solution.

Comment: @Markon hmmmm I dont think so

Comment: Ok. So basically each line has a dynamic number of characters. You should re-edit your question, because it seems the CSV has a fixed structure.

Comment: Edited :(each line is dynamic number of characters but the columns are fixed... hope i am making sense)

Comment: I think your DB approach is the correct one... Use a DB's bulk import to take the data, create a view over it returning it in a suitable key order, then use itertools.groupby to aggregate the results. Alternatively, look at a database with MapReduce and get that to do the heavy lifting

Comment: Also, if you have 200 million rows, why isn't this stuff in a database already? You normally only end up with that many rows from an export...

Comment: Btw, what are those crazy data formats??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
content='''
   **001**     Math        **02/20/2013**  A

   **001**     Literature  **03/02/2013**  B

   **002**     Biology     **01/01/2013**  A

   **003**     Biology     **04/08/2013**  A

   **001**     Biology     **05/01/2013**  B

   **002**     Math        **03/10/2013**  C
'''

from collections import defaultdict

lines = content.split("\n")
items_iter = (line.split() for line in lines if line.strip())

aggregated = defaultdict(list)

for items in items_iter:
    stud, class_, date, grade = (t.strip('*') for t in items)
    aggregated[stud].append((class_, grade, date))

for stud, data in aggregated.iteritems():
    full_grades = [';'.join(items) for items in data]
    print '{},#{}'.format(stud, '#'.join(full_grades))
```

Output:

```
003,#Biology;A;04/08/2013
002,#Biology;A;01/01/2013#Math;C;03/10/2013
001,#Math;A;02/20/2013#Literature;B;03/02/2013#Biology;B;05/01/2013
```

Of course, this is an ugly hackish code just to show you how it can be done in python. When working with large streams of data, use [generators](http://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators) and [iterators](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html), and don't use `file.readlines()`, [just iterate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076024/in-python-is-read-or-readlines-faster). The iterators will not read all the data at once but read chunk-by-chunk when you iterate over them, and not earlier.

If you are concerned if 200m records fit memory, then do the following:

1. sort the records into separate "buckets" (like in [bucket sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort)) by students id

   `cat all_records.txt | grep 001 > stud_001.txt # do if for other students also`
2. do the processing per bucket
3. merge

`grep` is just example. make a fancier script (awk or also python) that will filter by student ID and, for example, filter all with ID < 1000, later 1000 < ID < 2000 and so on. You can do it safely because your records per student are disjoint.

Comment: If 200 million records fits in memory... (or at least the non-duplicated parts anyway)....

Comment: Jakub M.: 200 million * 1 byte ~ 200MB. So, if your line has 10 bytes, you need ~2GB of memory. The problem here is not the number of iterations, but "where" you store the lines.

Comment: @Markon even given 1 byte - factor in Python's object overhead, and it gets even smaller quicker...

Comment: @Jakub M Thank you very much. I will try your example and see how it behaves. Eventually this script will be running on a production windows environment. +1 for a quick solution.

Comment: Still, @JonClements suggestion about the database is the right way to go, if you a are not doing some single shot, throw-away script

Comment: @Jakum M I just realized the results are not ordered by date. Any idea how to achieve that.

Comment: use `sorted` and specify `key` parameter

Comment: @JakubM I did made some progress by converting your script to read from a file. But still date sorted is not working. Any help ?
 with open('student.txt','r') as data1:
  accounts = defaultdict(list)
  for line in data1:
    sid, subject, dateReg, rank = line.split()[:4]
    accounts[sid].append((subject, rank, dateReg))

print accounts
sortedData = sorted(accounts.iteritems(), key=operator.itemgetter(2))
for key, value in sortedData:
  print key
  print(value)
for sid, data1 in sortedData:
  report = [';'.join(items) for items in data1]
  print '{},#{}'.format(sid, '#'.join(report))