# file.write() jumps to a random position python 2.7

Tags: python

I was playing around in the interpreter and the file.write() method was acting weird, I'm hoping someone can explain it.

```
>>> file.seek(0)
>>> file.tell()
0
>>> file.readline()
'The Project Gutenberg EBook of The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes\n'
>>> file.tell()
65
>>> file.realine()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'realine'
>>> file.readline()
'by Sir Arthur Conan Doyle\n'
>>> file.tell()
91
>>> file.write("line\n")
>>> file.tell()
4101
>>>
```

Why did file.write("line\n") make it jump to 4101?

file is a copy of this: http://norvig.com/big.txt opened in r+ mode

Comment: What is the platform you are running this on? Windows, Linux, Mac, something else?

Comment: I'm running it on a Macbook Pro.

Comment: Your code is incomplete. How did you assign to `file`?

Comment: file = open('big.txt', 'r+')

Answer (score 6):

Some implementations of Python use a [read-ahead buffer for `readline`.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5076086/190597) So after calling `readline` the position of the filehandle is **not** necessarily at the end of the line just read.

Comment: Also note that 4101 is 4096 + 5 -- 5 is the length of `"line\n"`. 4096 is a pretty typical buffer size.

Comment: And you can reset the buffer with `file.seek(0, 1)`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not just buffers at work here:  if you're going to mix reading and writing a file, you **must** do a file-positioning operation (like `seek()`) between switching from reading to writing, or from writing to reading.  "must" means the behavior is undefined otherwise - it may or may not appear to work on any given platform, and on a single platform may appear to work in some cases but not in others.  Here's a link to an answer I gave in 2005 (LOL! it's an old problem), which contains references to the C standard (much of Python's file I/O behavior is inherited from the platform C libraries):

https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-bugs-list/2005-August/029886.html

Comment: Beautiful, thank you. I was having a similar problem using for line in file:, had a feeling I might end up doing this. Thanks for the confirmation.