# Having trouble writing output to a file

Tags: python

Below is my code, the problem that I'm working on is to have the output of my program "written to a file whose name is obtained by appending the string `_output` to the input file name".

What is the correct way of going about doing this?

```
fileName = raw_input('Enter the HTML file name:') + '.html'
f = open(fileName, 'r')
myList = f.readlines()
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    toString = ''.join(myList)
newString = toString.replace('<span>', '')
newString = newString.replace('</span>', '')
print newString  #testing the output
f.close()
```

Here is revised code. Something like this?

```
fileName = raw_input('Enter the HTML file name:') + '.html'
f = open(fileName, 'r')
fnew = open(fileName, 'w')
myList = f.readlines()
for i in range(0, len(myList)):
    toString = ''.join(myList)
newString = toString.replace('<span>', '')
newString = newString.replace('</span>', '')
fnew.write(newString)
f.close()
```

Comment: You are reading and not writing to a file. Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159900/correct-way-to-write-line-to-file-in-python

Comment: Is your question how to concatenate strings (just use `+`) or how to write to a file?

Comment: I didnt get code for write file, please provide that.

Comment: Hi, my question is how to write the output to a new file

Comment: you have to open another file in `w` mode. and call `write` on that file object. We can provide solution but first try your self, and provide code here. so we can solve your issue in write file.

Comment: Start with `open(filename + '_output', 'w')`

Comment: Something like this? edit: oops, hold on

Comment: sorry i'm new to this site

Comment: try something, if you made mistake, we are here to solve it. That way you can learn from your self. If we provide you solution, it might be not good for your learning. Make mistake in your code :)

Comment: what is the ouput of your code ?

Comment: I'm getting an error saying toString is not defined

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
fileName = raw_input('Enter the HTML file name:') + '.html'
f = open(fileName, 'r+')
toString = f.read()
newString = toString.replace('<span>', '')
newString = newString.replace('</span>', '')
print newString  #testing the output

f.truncate() #clean all content from the file
f.write(newString) #write to the file
f.close()
```

Please refer this post : [In Python, is read() , or readlines() faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5076024/in-python-is-read-or-readlines-faster)

If you want to print the output to a new file then;

```
new_file = open(new_file_path, 'w') #If the file does not exist, creates a new file for writing
new_file.write(newString)
new_file.close()
```

Now no need to open the first `html` file `read/write` use

```
f = open(fileName, 'r')
```

Comment: Could do `read()` instead of `readlines()` and join the lines, no?

Comment: @cricket_007. Thanks; Updated.

Comment: Ah, I should've mentioned that I can only use the functions/syntax that we learned in class. We never learned that truncate function. I understand the write function though, but how should I make a new file for that output? If I make a new variable like newFileName=raw_input and then make a new file called fnew for reading it would that work?